# Supermercados o Supermercado DIA

Tags: gramática

No entiendo por qué es “[Supermercados DIA](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Supermercados_DIA)” en vez de “Supermercado DIA”. ¿Por qué tiene que ser en plural? ¡Muchas gracias!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

En términos de almacenes o supermercados, se suele hablar de una *cadena* de almacenes, es decir un conjunto o grupo de varios elementos. En este caso sería la cadena de supermercados *XXX* (Ten en cuenta que la cadena de supermercado *XXX* suena extraño, por no decir incorrecto)

Comment: ¡Muchísimas gracias por sus explicaciones!

Answer (score 0):

No es que tenga que ser singular o plural, sino que se usa cada vez según sea necesario:

- los supermercados DÍA venden las cebollas a 1€/kg
- voy todas las semanas al supermercado DÍA de la esquina